# remove calendar icon for <af:inputDate>

Tags: java, calendar, jdeveloper

I have a  in the page and I don't want the calendar icon beside the input text. How can I remove that calendar icon?

Thank,
Shawn

Comment: Which version of  Oracle ADF are you using ?

Comment: @MrAdibou, it's 12c (Oracle IDE 12.2.1.2.42.161008.1648).

Comment: Why not just use af:inputText with appropriate DateTimeConverter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the calendar icon by customizing your Oracle ADF skin css:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/user.1111/e21420/adfsg_faces.htm#ADFSG581

> The process to change a component-specific selector is the same for
>   both the ADF Faces and ADF Data Visualization components. In the
>   Selector Tree, you expand the Faces Components Selectors or Data
>   Visualization Selectors node to select the selector of the component
>   you want to modify. You then set values for this selector using the
>   Property Inspector. You can also set properties for any
>   pseudo-elements, component style classes, component selector aliases,
>   or descendant selectors that the selector you select references.

In your case :

- Navigate to your skin
- Navigate to the **af:inputDate** pseudo-elements named **launch-icon-style** in the design panel of the skin
- Set it's **Display** property in the property inspector from **inline** to **none**:

  af|inputDate::launch-icon-style
  {
    display: none; 
  }